# I want to get data to the dropdown by using another dropdown in the same page

Tags: laravel

I have a dropdown on my page to load districts. And I have another dropdown to load Divisions according to that selected district. The below code I have got all the divisions. But I want only the divisions according to the selected districts. How can I do?

```
@php
    $districtAll=\App\District::all();

@endphp
<div class="row">
    <label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="district">9. District</label>
    <div class="col-md-8">
        <select name="district">
            <option type="text" class="detail-wp" value="">Select District</option>

            @foreach($districtAll as $all)
                <option value="{{$all->DISTRICT_ID}}">{{$all->DISTRICT}} </option>
            @endforeach
        </select>
    </div>
</div>
<br>
@php
    $getDsAll=\App\DsDivision::all();
@endphp
<div class="row">
    <label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="ds_division">10. DS Division</label>
    <div class="col-md-8">
        <select name="ds_division" class="form-control">
            <option type="text" class="detail-wp" value=""></option>

            @foreach($getDsAll as $all)
                <option value="{{$all->DIVISION_ID}}">{{$all->DIVISION}} </option>
            @endforeach
        </select>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Sounds like you're after a dynamic dropdown. Check [this tutorial](https://talltips.novate.co.uk/livewire/dynamic-cascading-dropdown-with-livewire) which uses Livewire. Alternatives using other JavaScript technologies are available.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it using ajax request:

```
$('select[name=district]').on('change', function(){
    $districtId = $(this).val();
    $.get('/division/district/'+$districtId).done(function(res){
       $.each(res, function (key, value) {
         $('select[name=ds_division]').append(`<option value='` + value.id + `'>` + value.name +`</option>`);
    });
});
```

to make this working you will need a route like

```
Route::get("/division/district/{district}", "DivisionController@getByDistrictId");
```

DivisionController@getByDistrictIdwill be

```
public function getByDistrictId($district)
{
  return Division::where('district_id',$district)->get();
}
```

this code just to give you an idea of how you can do it.